# Issue with input change event and input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a radio button, a text field and a select field.
This is the html code:

```
<div class="wb-success-delivery">
 <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="0" /><span> Now)</span>
</div>
<div class="success-delivery">
  <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="2"  />
   <input type="text"  class="test" id="del_time_rang2"  value="Tomorrow" name="delivery" />
     <select id="del_time_rang" >  
      <option value="11-12pm">11-12pm</option> 
      <option value="12-1pm">12-1pm</option> 
      <option value="1-2pm">1-2pm</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

I've then got some jQuery code with a change function to store the information that was selected by the user above.

```
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j("input[name='delivery']").change(function(){
  var $jtime= $j('#del_time_rang').val();
  var $jdate= $j('#del_time_rang2').val();
  var $jresult=  $jdate + ' between ' + $jtime ;

    if($j("input[name='delivery']:checked").val()==0) {
        $j("#del_time_1").val('Now');
        $j("#del_time_2").val('Now');
    } else if($j("input[name='delivery']:checked").val()==2) {
        $j("#del_time_1").val($jresult);
        $j("#del_time_2").val($jresult);
    }
});

});
```

Now this works for `#del_time_rang2` but for `#del_time_rang` it only works if the user selects the right option first and then clicks the radio button. Otherwise it shows the default (11-12pm).
I assume this is because the change event is for the radio button input, but not sure how I can fix it? Any Ideas?

Comment: it's in magento

Comment: You want it to work only during the onchange event of radio or you can have submit kind of button?

Comment: Why not just hide / show the date inputs when the second radio is selected?  By binding the values to whatever these are `#del_time_*` means that you would also need to set up events to onchange of the select and onkeyup (or blur) of the input so that the new values would be assigned whenever they were changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should attach `onChange` event to the `select` also, so:

- I've added `name="delivery"` to the select
- Attached `onChange` event to `$("[name='delivery']")`

See follow:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[name='delivery']").change(function(){
  var $jtime= $('#del_time_rang').val();
  var $jdate= $('#del_time_rang2').val();
  var $jresult=  $jdate + ' between ' + $jtime ;

    if($("input[name='delivery']:checked").val()==0) {
        $("#del_time_1").val('Now');
        $("#del_time_2").val('Now');
    } else if($("input[name='delivery']:checked").val()==2) {
        $("#del_time_1").val($jresult);
        $("#del_time_2").val($jresult);
    }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wb-success-delivery">
 <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="0" /><span> (Now)</span>
</div>
<div class="success-delivery">
  <input type="radio" name="delivery" value="2"  />
   <input type="text"  class="test" id="del_time_rang2"  value="Tomorrow" name="delivery" />
     <select id="del_time_rang" name="delivery" >  
      <option value="11-12pm">11-12pm</option> 
      <option value="12-1pm">12-1pm</option> 
      <option value="1-2pm">1-2pm</option>
 </select>
</div>
<input type="text" id="del_time_1">
```

Note: Anyway I think that `selector` should be used the "class" attribute instead the "name" attribute.

I hope it helps you, bye.